# Display dynamically nested object as a table in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use nested object to display fields in a table. (using Material UI and formik)
My rows table are ordered by year so I have:

```
<Formik initialValues={{
                2018: {
                    other: 1,
                    year: 2018,
                    number: 1,
                    name: "Jim",
                    surname: "Jon",
                },
                2019: {
                    other: 1,
                    year:2019,
                    number: 1,
                    name: "Tun",
                    surname: "Ton",
                }}
                    onSubmit={()=>{}}>
```

To use nested Object I could do:

```
       <Form>
         <Field name="2018.name" />
         <Field name="2019.name" />
         <button type="submit">Submit</button>
       </Form>
```

But if my response return something different from mine It don't works.
How can I fix it?

I'd tried like this:

```
export const REPORT_IVASS_FORM_INIT_VALUES = Object.freeze({
    "year": '',
    "name": '',
    "surname": '',
    "number": '',
    "other": '',
})
```

and after:

```
response.map(el => 

<Field 
   name={response.2018[el.key]
   type="text"
}
/>
)
```

but firstly response.2018[el.key], after response.2019[el.key] and so on.

But obviously it don't work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use key inside it , you can use it like this

```
       { 
response.map((el,index) => {
        return <div key={index}>
        
        <Field 
           name={response.name[el.index]
           } type="text" />
        
        </div>
    
    })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

looking at your initial value, it looks as if you receive an object, ordered by year where the year is unique. You should use a map function to return JSX for each year, and use a unique key for the key prop.

You can use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to iterate and map over your initial data or api data, if its the same (an object) as your initial data

```
   <Form>
     {Object.values(initialValues).map((value) =>
         <Field 
             key={value.year} 
             name={value.name} 
             type="text"
         />
     )}
     <button type="submit">Submit</button>
   </Form>
```

Comment: sorry I have modified the description, could you check again?

Comment: I'm not sure what changes. Using Object.values, you can iterate over some dynamic object and return jsx, since Object.values converts an object into an array of its values. Can you provide a minimal workable solution on codesandbox to better explain what the issue is?